# SQL SERVER - Order By

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

hi im using sql server 2019
use northwind database
I want customers to be sorted by country. With the difference that first it is the United States, Germany and France and then it is an ascending order according to the rest of the countries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Gordon's answer will keep mentioned countries in the last.

You need to use case expression as follows:

```
order by (case when country in ('United States', 'Germany', 'France') then 0
          else 1 
          end),
         country
```

If you want specific order within the mentioned countries then use multiple when as follows:

```
order by (case when country = 'United States' then 0
               When country = 'Germany' then 1
               When country = 'France' then 2 
               else 3 
          end),
         country
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use a `case` expression in the `order by`:

```
order by (case when country in ('United States', 'Germany', 'France') then 1 else 0 end),
         country
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your code more flexible, consider adding a 'MetaOrder' column to your country table, which would then give you a lot of flexibility wrt sorting.

You would then use `SORT BY MetaOrder ASC, Country ASC`

With that structure, you can in the future add/remove countries from the 'top' list and even have several levels, eg GER, USA, FRA first (0 in their MetaOrder column), then the EU countries in alphabetical order (all having a 1 in the MetaOrder column) and then the rest of the world in alphabetical order (all having a 2 in the MetaOrder column).

If you wanted to order GER, USA, FRA in that order, you would assign them 0, 1 and 2 respectively, then all the EU countries a 3 and the ROW a 4 etc.

Later updates to the desired sort would merely require updates to the table and not to the SQL, making it user configurable.